# Audit records while working with streaming data in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a use case wherein records will be published from an on-premise system to a PubSub topic. Now, I want to make sure that all records published are read by the Apache Beam job and they are all correctly written to BigQuery.
I have two questions regarding this:
1) How do I make sure that there is no data loss in the entire process?
2) I need to maintain an Audit table somewhere to make sure that if 'n' records were published I have dumped each one of them successfully. How to keep track of the records?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Dataflow guarantees exactly-once data processing, with transactional logic built into its sources and sinks. You can read more about exactly-once guarantees in the blog article: [After Lambda: Exactly-once processing in Cloud Dataflow, Part 3 (sources and sinks)](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-cloud-dataflow-part-3-sources-and-sinks).

For your question about an audit table: can you describe more about what you'd like to accomplish? Dataflow has built-in [Elements Added](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf#total-execution-time) counters available in the UI and API which will show exactly how many elements have been processed. You could match this up with the number of published Pub/Sub messages.